# primeFaces LazyLoading datatable inside another dataTable and rowExpansion

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, lazy-loading

I am using primeFaces 3.4.2 and have implemented Lazy Loading Data Table with sorting, filtering.
I am trying to embed another datatable inside the above mentioned data table.

I have used row expansion and row toggler for the above purpose.

My scenerio is something like this

```
public class Customer {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    @JoinColumn(unique = true, name = "Cust_Details_Id" )
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private CustomerDetails customerDetails;
}

public class CustomerDetails {
    @Id
    private Long cdId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "customerDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<TypeA> listOfTypeA = new ArrayList<TypeA>(); 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<TypeB> listOfTypeB = new ArrayList<TypeB>();;
}

public classTypeA {
    @Id
    private Long typeAId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private MeasurementDetails measurementDetails;    

    // Around 10-12 fields to store its details
}

public classTypeB {
    @Id
    private Long typeBId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private MeasurementDetails measurementDetails;    

    // Around 12-15 fields to store its details
}
```

//I am using LazyLoading like below code

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" 
var="customer" 
value="#{customerController.lazyModel}" 
styleClass="userDataTableStyle"
paginator="true" 
rows="10" 
selection="#{customerController.selctedCustomers}"
paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
lazy="true" 
rowsPerPageTemplate="10,15,50" >

<f:facet name="header">Customer List</f:facet>  

<p:column> <p:rowToggler id="rowToggler" /> </p:column>            
<p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:18px" />  

<p:column headerText="First Name" sortBy="#{customer.firstName}" filterBy="#{customer.firstName}">
    <f:facet name="header"> <p:outputLabel  value="First Name" /> </f:facet>

    <p:commandLink value="#{customer.firstName}" update=":customerDetailForm:display" oncomplete="custDialog.show()"  title="View">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{customer}" target="#{customerController.selectedCustomer}" />    
    </p:commandLink>
</p:column>

<!-- Other Columns -->
<!-- I want to embed another data here but based on the previous selected customers row Toggle -->

<p:rowExpansion  id="expand" rendered="true"  >  

    <p:dataTable id="dataTableInner" 
        var="cust" 
        value="#{customerController.selctedCustomers}" 
        styleClass="userDataTableStyle"
        lazy="true" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,15,50">

    <f:facet name="header"> Customer Details </f:facet>

    <p:column headerText="Customer Details " sortBy="#{customer.customerDetails}" >
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:outputLabel  value="Customer Details" />
        </f:facet>
        <p:outputLabel  value="#{customer.customerDetails.customerId}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Mas ccc" >
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:outputLabel  value="Date" />
        </f:facet>
        <p:outputLabel  value="#{customer.customerDetails.TypeA[0]}" /> <!-- Example -->
    </p:column>

    </p:dataTable> <!-- Inner datatable -->
</p:rowExpansion> 
</p:dataTable> <!-- Outer datatable -->
```

Questions

1. How do I know which customer has been "Row Toggeled" not via Checkbox which I am using for delete 
2. I want to display a dataTable of TypeA and TypeB (if data is present in the list), it gets triggered upon row toggler
3. I am maintaining customerDetails class to keep track of lists of TypeA and TypeB, 
    Shall I remove this class and simply stick the Lists into Customer Class itself?

// It can have Zero or One TypeA list, similarly for TypeB too, in Customer Details Class
Please Help me if My design is incorrect and provide some pointers so that I can get this to working